# VirtualDub for Linux

Tags: linux, video, mencoder, virtualdub

Is there VirtualDub analogue in Linux? I know there is `MEncoder` but it runs in console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[AviDemux](http://avidemux.org/) is the closest thing for editing (not recording, though).

Comment: Looks nice. I'll try it.